# Retrieving list of all installed printers via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, printing

I have been given a screenshot from a web page which shows the list of all installed printers accessible by the client (local and network ones) in a combobox and let user select one. Even there is a button to refresh the list!

I do not have access to the page and cannot prove the functionality. Is that even possible to do this or simulate this job by any means in a web page?

Comment: Web-based apps cannot do so. The browser cannot do such a thing unless there is some kind of java applet, flash, or, Silverlight based app. And even if so, such programs may have issues gathering such data. Because the browser environment cannot poke your os for such kind of information. That would be a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say that it's most likely a list of network printers, retrieved via some server-side code. The "Refresh" button seems to back that up as there's obviously AJAX at play. Simply, though, there's no way to get this information client-side via JavaScript, so there's got to be something else going on.

Comment: I agree with you but this service is presented to all the subscribed clients all over the world (as I have been told) and list of printers is specific for each client. I wanted to consult to other developers here before giving my final opinion to the boss :)

Comment: Sounds like a feature that was designed by marketing. Joe Marketer: "Wouldn't it be great if we could let users pick a printer." Bob Executive: "Great idea. Yeah. Let's do that." Neither one has any idea about whether such a thing is actually possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use neodynamic's product. No ActiveX, no flash etc. only install small app on clien side(its free) but .net sdk or php sdk is not free.

Web Site:
http://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/aspnet-mvc/download/

Sample:
https://github.com/neodynamic/WebClientPrint2-MVC5-Sample

Answer (score 1):

On linux,
http://localhost:631/printers/  works.
If you have the CUPS service installed, al you need is to post an HTTP request to your printer. HTTP GET/ will list all printers.

Comment: Hi, can you share some useful link?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be possible on Windows, but I'm not a Windows-guy so I can't evaluate this: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/104211/How-to-get-the-client-printer-name-using-JavaScrip

Comment: This example is using ActiveX object. Basically things likr ActiveX, Java Applet and Flash are off the table.