# Angular 6 printing in client side

Tags: angular

I have a question, to find dot matrix or laser printer connected in the client side for print and give html/PDF/text to printer, to print using angular 6.

Comment: It is not possible to get the list of `printers` using **pure** JS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529877/retrieving-list-of-all-installed-printers-via-javascript
The most you can do is `onClick`, call `window.print()` and use `@media print` to hide the unwanted elements [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Comment: please follow this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-print)