# Is there any way to get default printer in javascript/nativescript?

Tags: javascript, java, android, ios

I'm new to app development and I'm trying to get the default printer name from the device and send it to a 3rd party API. I've found 'javax.print.PrintServiceLookup' which can get the default printer but I need this in javascript/typescript.

Is there anything available to use this library in my code? I'm developing this app for both Android and ios

Comment: Related: [Retrieving list of all installed printers via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529877/retrieving-list-of-all-installed-printers-via-javascript). Please also edit your question to clarify if you want this code to run on a webpage, or if you are writing native apps for android, windows, mac, ios etc.

Comment: if you want to get a list of printers in browser environment, you can stop trying. You can't do that, for obvious reasons (security being the most obvious)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement this for two OSes! Android -> JAVA and IOS -> (Obj-C/Swift MAC OS)

Comment: For now, we are trying to develop it for android only. I found an android library called Printservice but it can printer name only from a service implemented using this class, not the default service available in android.